# What is encryption strength when TcpClientCredentialType.Windows is used?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security, net.tcp

What encryption algorithm and key length is used on the following binding?

```
NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.Transport;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.Windows;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729700.aspx):

> The NetTcpBinding class uses TCP for message transport. Security for the transport mode is provided by implementing Transport Layer Security (TLS) over TCP. The TLS implementation is provided by the operating system.

So it's going to depend on your operating system which version of TLS is used. For Server 2008 R2, [TLS 1.2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_1.2_.28SSL_3.3.29) is used.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I could see how when TLS is used, the key length will be whatever the key length is on the certificate (when ClientCredentialType is Certificate). My question is specifically about when ClientCredentialType is Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Using windows credential means it will use your windows credential which is used to log on Windows as the client identifier, it's going to use windows validation. 
This MSDN link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733836.aspx) may help you.

Comment: I might be missing something... Where does it tell me what encryption algorithm is used with windows creds?